# How can i resolve my build error about maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I've tried to build a project with Maven. In the folder where there's pom.xml file I've launched git bash and used "mvn compile" command but I got a build failure with following message:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.905 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-12T10:21:58+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project unitime: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: <a href="https://github.com/UniTime/unitime.git">Git repository</a>, here there's pom.xml file; I'm using jdk 11.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a configuration section to your `maven-compiler-plugin` in your `pom.xml` file and set source and target to eg. 1.8.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is your Java Version 1.8 as well?

Comment: My jdk is 11.0.2

Comment: @Giuseppe Boezio in this pom.xml that you provided (https://github.com/UniTime/unitime/blob/master/pom.xml)  you can find a section that I provided in my comment above. As you can see there is source and target set to 1.5. Just change it to 1.6 or above and then try to run "mvn compile".